# How to foreach data array and entering data to array child $arrayTw?

Tags: php, arrays

I have data array in variable $tw, i want to manipulate value $tw in new array child, here my code:

```
static public function getTrackTwitter($hashtag, $media)
{

        $tw = Twitter::getSearch(['q' => $hashtag, 'count' => 100, 'result_type' => 'mixed', 'until' => '', 'format' => 'array']);
        foreach ($tw['statuses'] as $key => $value) {
            // $date       = date('M d',strtotime($value['created_at']));

            $arrayTw = array(
                'caption' => $value['text'],
                'code'    => $value['id'],
                // 'created' => $date,
                'user'    => $value['user']['screen_name'],
                'user_img'=> $value['user']['profile_image_url'],
                'likes'   => $value['favorite_count'],
                'comments'=> $value['retweet_count'],
                'engage'  => $value['favorite_count'] + $value['retweet_count'],
                'media'   => 'tw'
            );
            return $arrayTw;
        }

}
```

why return $arrayTw only print 1 data? why not looping data?

Comment: You're returning in the middle of the loop, so the function ends

Comment: You does to put return $arrayTw; after the end of your foreach }

Comment: it was try put return $arrayTw; after the end of foreach but same print only 1 data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new array element (use `[]`) each iteration instead of overwriting the `$arrayTw` variable.  Then `return` after the loop:

```
static public function getTrackTwitter($hashtag, $media)
{
    $tw = Twitter::getSearch(['q' => $hashtag, 'count' => 100, 'result_type' => 'mixed', 'until' => '', 'format' => 'array']);

    foreach ($tw['statuses'] as $key => $value) {
        // $date       = date('M d',strtotime($value['created_at']));
        $arrayTw[] = array(
            'caption' => $value['text'],
            'code'    => $value['id'],
            // 'created' => $date,
            'user'    => $value['user']['screen_name'],
            'user_img'=> $value['user']['profile_image_url'],
            'likes'   => $value['favorite_count'],
            'comments'=> $value['retweet_count'],
            'engage'  => $value['favorite_count'] + $value['retweet_count'],
            'media'   => 'tw'
        );
    }
    return $arrayTw;
}
```